# How to pass intent in adapter class

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-intent, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to navigate from one activity to another using intent but my application is crashing when the onclick method is called giving null pointer exception here is the code of my adapter class.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(absadapter.exViewHolder holder, final int position){
    holder.exname.setText(exList.get(position).name);
    holder.exlogo.setImageResource(exList.get(position).logoId);
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 0) {
                Intent intent=new Intent(context,crunches.class);
                context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
    });


}
```

Here is the logcat error:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.ruchit.totalfitness, PID: 1481
              java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
                  at android.content.ComponentName.<init>(ComponentName.java:130)
                  at android.content.Intent.<init>(Intent.java:5787)
                  at com.example.ruchit.totalfitness.absadapter$1.onClick(absadapter.java:60)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6312)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24811)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:171)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6649)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

Comment: post error from logcat.

Comment: Your `context` might be `null`.

Comment: The Logcat should point out which object is null. Please post it out for us to help.
Most likey `context` is null.

Comment: you can use this  holder.itemView.context.startActivity(intent)

Comment: `context` might be null, so pass your activity context to adapter when you create it then you can use that context in adapter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(context,crunches.class);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

**To**

```
v.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(v.getContext(), crunches.class));
```

Hope it helps.!

Comment: Welcome glad to help.! Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

It's not the responsibility of the holder or the adapter to start the activity ! 
[SOLID](https://wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28informatique%29) principle S say Single Object Responsibility ! The holder role it's only to display values and handling click but not do the click behavior ! You should do that in the activity that init the recycler and the adpater by using interface or more easilly [Butterknife](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus)

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (position == 0) {
                EventBus.getDefault().post(new OnClickEvent())
            }
        }
    });
```

in the activity

```
@Subscribe(threadMode = Thread.MAIN)
public void onClickItem(OnClickEvent event) {
      startActivity(new Intent(this,crunches.class));
}
```

moreover you don't need to pass context to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

i see that u have fixed it, but try changing

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(context,crunches.class);
```

to

```
 Intent intent=new Intent(this,crunches.class);
```

am curious if it will work

Comment: This will not work i've passed the intent in my adapter class which will be loaded into my main class hence by simply passing (this,crunches.class) it'll not be able to point to main class and null pointer exception will be generated hence the best way is to use getcontext() to solve this.